# Display tooltip over NSSearchfield in Kiosk Screen Mode

Tags: macos, cocoa, tooltip, nssearchfield, kiosk-mode

I have implemented kiosk screen using the carbon api "CGDisplayCapture( kCGDirectMainDisplay )" and I have a NSSearchField over a kiosk view.

```
mysearchField = [ [ NSSearchField alloc ] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect(..) ];
[mysearchField setToolTip:@"My String"];
[[mysearchField cell] setPlaceholderString:@"My PlaceholderString"];
[fullBrowserView addSubview: mysearchField ];
```

When I disable kiosk screen,I can see the tooltip on searchfield.But In kiosk screen ,tooltip is not getting displayed.I feel CGDisplayCapture is blocking the tooltip.

Is there any other way to do this.